# How to check if a file with random changing name is downloaded using protractor selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, end-to-end

This is the path of file

```
 capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory':  'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I download the file with this,

```
productDashboardPageObject.exportDashboard();
```

It downloads the file, but I am not able to check if it was downloaded. It has only count in name, so I can check if it contains count.

After all is done I will delete files, so only those files will stay after I download.

I did lots of things but could not manage.

Also, another way is if service is sending 200 response. But i think it is harder to do?

Please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it.**

The idea is to *clean up the download directory before the test* and use `glob.sync()` function continuously called inside a [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) Expected Condition.

The complete code:

```
var glob = require("glob");

browser.driver.wait(function () {
    var filesArray = glob.sync(filePattern);
    if (typeof filesArray !== 'undefined' && filesArray.length > 0) {
        // this check is necessary because `glob.sync` can return
        // an empty list, which will be considered as a valid output
        // making the wait to end.
        return filesArray;
    }
}, timeout).then(function (filesArray) {
    var filename = filesArray[0];
    // now we have the filename and can do whatever we want
});
```

You just need to define a `filePattern` - the glob file pattern to match your file - it can be `*.*` if you don't want to be specific. Or, for example, it could be `*.xls` if this is an Excel file.

Also see:

- [protractor: test download file without knowing filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082777/protractor-test-download-file-without-knowing-filename)

Comment: Message:
    Failed: Wait timed out after 18167ms
  Stack:
    Error: Wait timed out after 18167ms
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: <anonymous wait>

Answer (score 1):

The response code is not possible. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137881/how-to-use-protractor-to-get-the-response-status-code-and-response-text/25149395#25149395).

But you can solve your problem using *count* pattern. The idea is to skip files in the target folder which you know are not your downloaded file **before the test**. Keep all its names in a list. After the download, fetch the names of the files in the folder and check if the difference in size is equal to 1 - and that the name of this new file contains *count* in its name.

If you run another tests before cleaning the folder, add this new file folder to the skip files names list that you created at the start.

Comment: i also want to do those check but i dont know how to do. if i can do, i will get the size of of folders inside that download folder then after downloaded, check again to compare if +1

Comment: Just to make explicit: What I mean by folder is size is the number of files inside it. Here you can found out how to do it in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362888/getting-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-in-java